# Подключение phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Задача: подключить phpmailer для формы обратной связи на сайте.
Для начала решил разобраться как работает он в принципе и потом подключать к форме. 
Но появилась неисчезающая проблема:

> 2019-09-22 19:09:21 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Перепробовал все: проверил подключен ли open_ssl, разблокировал подключение небезопасных подключений на gmail, подключал форму через два разных локальных сервера: Open Server, xampp. Пытался отправлять и с почты gmail и с почты mail.ru. Менял ssl и tls, ставил разные порты: и 465 и 578.
В одном источнике писали, что локальный сервер может конфликтовать со скайпом - скайп был отключен, проблема не пропала.
В php не силен, хотелось просто подключить данную форму, но с умом, понимая, что откуда следует.
Буду благодарен за помощь.
Код:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;   
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";


$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                        // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->isSMTP();                                  // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                      // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'h******n';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'h******l';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';     // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = '465';                        // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('h**********m', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('s**********u', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                           // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host).
Нужно добавить вот такую часть кода:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для Google помимо настройки PHPMailer необходимо в настройках почты отметить галочку "разрешить отправлять письма по SMTP"

По правильной настройке PHPMailer в связке с Google есть развёрнутый ответ по указанным ниже ссылкам:

1. [Настройка Google-почты для отправки писем](https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/kak-ispolzovat-smtp-server#-1-8211-Google-SMTP)
2. [Настройка PHPMailer для отправки писем с Google](https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/kak-ispolzovat-smtp-server#-2-8211-Google-SMTP)